# What time zone does svn use if I update by datetime and don't specify time zone

Tags: svn, datetime

Let's say I execute the following command at the shell in a svn repository:

```
$ svn update -r {"2011-01-01 12:00"}
```

What time zone does it use?  Is it:

- UTC?
- My machine's local time zone?
- Local time zone of the machine that holds the svn repository?
- ???

I couldn't locate this information the svn documentation on [Revision Specifiers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is interpreted in your machine's local timezone. So if you are locally at GTM -5h, then 12:00 will be interpreted as 17:00 UTC.

If you would like to explicitly specify another timezone as supported by the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats then you can do that also. The documentation you link to has such examples.

Note that the timezone of the machine that holds the svn repository is never used for anything; internally the repository always stores commit times in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You specify local server time when commit was made.